# Run-Time Check Failure #2 dissapears when I define a completely new variable int i = 0 without using it

Tags: c++, opencv

When I run this code I get the error:

Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'line' was corrupted.

---

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#pragma comment(lib,  "ws2_32.lib") 
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#include "VisionUtils.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>



using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    static std::string dm_ext = ".xml";

    std::ifstream testFileNames("training_data\\testFiles.txt");
    std::string line;
    //int i = 0;

    std::cout << "Main loop start" << std::endl;

    if (testFileNames.is_open()){
        while (std::getline(testFileNames, line))//main loop
        {
            cout << line << endl;
            cout << "training_data\\depth\\" + line + dm_ext << endl;
            cv::FileStorage depthData("training_data\\depth\\" + line + dm_ext, cv::FileStorage::READ);
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

---

Now if I simply define int i = 0 before the loop, the error disappears

```
int main(void)
{
    static std::string dm_ext = ".xml";

    std::ifstream testFileNames("training_data\\testFiles.txt");
    std::string line;
    int i = 0;

    std::cout << "Main loop start" << std::endl;

    if (testFileNames.is_open()){
        while (std::getline(testFileNames, line))//main loop
        {
            cout << line << endl;
            cout << "training_data\\depth\\" + line + dm_ext << endl;
            cv::FileStorage depthData("training_data\\depth\\" + line + dm_ext, cv::FileStorage::READ);
        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

---

I am trying to adapt and improve a code that a previous engineer has created and I am not quite familiar with it yet. The code seems to be using an older version of opencv2, though I haven't been able to determine which one. I plan on upgrading to the current version of opencv in the future but I need to do some performance evaluation using the old code and am there fore bound to using that for now.

I would be glad to hear from anyone if they have an idea as to what is causing this weird behavior and how to fix the error I am having.

---

This is my first post on stackoverflow so please let me know if you see anything that I can improve on in my post.

Comment: What exactly is depthData? This seems to me like some sort of buffer overrun on line, although I'm not clear how that could happen with std::string. Perhaps you should check the contents of i after running the loop and see if they are not 0.

Comment: I'm inclined to the buffer overrun as well, the fact that the problems disappears by adding int i = 0 ; could be explained with the fact that the memory overwritten has moved down the stack and escapes the tun time checks enabled in debug builds.

Comment: @William Kappler
So I checked the content of i and it remains at value 0.

I am using the variable depthData to load frames containing depth data recorded by a kinect. The frames (cv::mat) were saved using cv::FileStorage in a different program.

Comment: @marom
So does this imply that defining int i = 0 just hides the error?

Comment: I suspect so. These errors are likely to show this kind of behaviour.

Comment: I'm not so sure if the int remains 0. I suppose it might merely be trying to access data beyond the string, not write to it, but it's still unusual. Unfortunately without any experience in opencv, I can't offer much more. You might want to address the question to someone connected to it if you don't get an answer here.